# How to automate new query from CSV and save to XLSX

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlsx

I am starting in the world of Data analysis and Python and my current job is import large CSV files with tweets and save them as xlsx, with format:Unicode UTF-8. I have been doing it the classic way one by one, but I have over hundreds of them and more will come so I need to automate it.
The process I need to do is the following in order to not loose data.

[image]

I have tried to do it with python but so far only managed to do it folder by folder ( improve from file by file) but te code looses some data and I think that is because It only opens as csv the file and saves it as xlsx ( I don't know it exactly because the code is a collection from others in the internet, sorry).

```
    import os
currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
os.chdir (currentDirectory)
import os
import glob
import csv
import openpyxl # from https://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/ or PyPI (e.g. via pip)

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
            for c, val in enumerate(row, start=1):
                ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value = val
    wb.save(csvfile.replace ('.csv', '.xlsx')) #.csv' + '.xlsx')
```

I am trying to improve it adding new things but if someone knows how to do the exact process in Python or VBA or another language I would be so grateful if you could share.

Edit: To answer the comment and to after running some file comparisons it seems that the only difference is the format, but it doesn't seem to be a loss in data itself. However my client is asking me to make it auto but maintaining the format of the first one. The first one is the format I want and the second one is the automicatially generated file:

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate on "code loses some data"? Is this rows or columns from the CSV not getting transferred to the Excel file, or is it some CSV files not being processed?

Comment: It turns out that it wasn´t a data loss, it is the format that changed so I modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `openpyxl` directly, I would use `pandas`, which internally uses `openpyxl` to do the detailed work. Together with the standard library `pathlib`, this short script will do the same:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

p = Path('.')
for csvfile in list(p.glob('**/*.csv')):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    excelfile = csvfile.with_suffix('.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(excelfile)
    print(csvfile.parent, csvfile.name, excelfile.name)
```

Comment: Hello, i used your code but an error with the URLs started to appear, is the following one:  since it exceeds Excel's limit of 65,530 URLS per worksheet.
Ignoring url xxxxx  warn ("Ignoring URL '%s' since it exceeds Excel's limit of "

Comment: It seems that collecting this in Excel might not really be a good way to go forward. Maybe a local database would be better. But it depends on what you need to do with the collected data.